# Storing same data under 2 keys

Tags: redis

I am working on a small user auth server that has to store minimal data about the user like `uuid`, `email`, `role`...

It already uses redis to store OTP codes for sign-in flow, so I figured it could also work nicely to store user data.

The issue is that I need to access this user data based on 2 keys `email` when users sign-in (`uuid` is not known here) and `uuid` in every other occasion (it is embeded as payload in jwt tokens, plus is more reliable than email as it can be changed).

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to access same user data using their `email` or `uuid` as key, without having to replicate it for both.

Comment: i don't think redis supports this. maybe via lua script to abstract it from the client but i think that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys in Redis aren't pointers—they are entries in a large hash table. You'll need to duplicate the data.